# Difference between "saya" and "falda"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, ropa

When I search, I see that "saya" is used in folklore context, so is "saya" a folkloric skirt or only a synonym for "falda"?

Wordreference Spanishdict RAE says "Vestidura talar antigua, especie de túnica, que usaban los hombres./Regalo en dinero que en equivalencia de vestido solían dar las reinas a sus servidoras cuando estas se casaban."

Comment: could you provide the sources in which you search?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, "saia" is the Portuguese word for "falda" (skirt).

Comment: @fedorqui Wordreference Spanishdict RAE. RAE says "Vestidura talar antigua, especie de túnica, que usaban los hombres./Regalo en dinero que en equivalencia de vestido solían dar las reinas a sus servidoras cuando estas se casaban."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Saya* is an archaic synonym of *falda*. Before it came to mean *falda* it referred to medieval Spanish style petticoats generally.

It still has currency as a loanword in some languages which Spanish has had contact with: e.g. Cebuano, Asturian, Moroccan Arabic, Tagalog.

Comment: Also saia in portuguese

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As it's not exactly a synonym, could "saya" be used for more archaic, or more formal, or more folkloric skirts?

Comment: @Quidam - Are you asking whether it could be used with such a meaning NOW (*hoy día*)?